# Why sidebar dropdown menu is not working bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just trying to create a simple left sidebar navigation menu. But the dropdown is not working, though I have add the js. I'm using minified version of bootstrap 3.

Here's my html  code

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- Sidebar Navigation -->
        <nav class="left-navbar navbar hidden-xs" role="navigation">
            <div id="profile">
                <div class="pic"></div>
                <div class="name">
                    <h2>Personal Site</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="tag">
                    <h3>A simple blogging site</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-menu">
                <ul class="nav-menu nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toogle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Projects
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Project Blog</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

And here is the custom CSS I'm using for sidebar

```
    .left-navbar {
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #333333;
    overflow-x: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #222222;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #222222;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #222222;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#profile {
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#profile .pic {
    background-image: url('../img/profile.jpg');
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#profile .name h2 {
    font-family: "Alegreya Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
}
#profile .tag h3 {
    font-family: "Buenard", serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0 25px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu ul li a {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the page ?

Comment: No, but there is a notice I can see from chrome inspect element `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Comment: It's not an error. Your javascript is clean.

Comment: So what am I missing?

Comment: Try eliminating your custom CSS and see if it works.

Comment: This is strange. Do you have an online version of this page?

Comment: No, testing it on local server. I'm using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js. Can this be the issue?

Comment: No. It's surely not. and if it is, you would see a javascript error in your error console.

Comment: I have uploaded those file to online server. Please check it at http://html.setmyself.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss-spelled `data-toggle` in your dropdown triggering link, you wrote it `data-toogle`. Change it to `data-toggle` and it will work.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for noticing it. Working.